# Upgrading Gmail from standard to premium

Tags: gmail

I am the domain licensee but not the administrator. The administrator is currently uncontactable.

**How do I upgrade from standard to premium Gmail?**

Google is making it so difficult for customers to upgrade (contribute more revenue to them!).

Answer (score 2):

Is the domain in your name? If it is, then I would suggest trying to get in touch with someone at the [Google Apps sales team](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/request.py?contact_type=premier) and seeing what they can do for you.

I find that if you're trying to spend money with someone they're more likely to help you than if you just wanted the control panel back from the standard version.